# Regex Help - Named capture group that ends in two possible ways

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture a group that has a variety of different forms.

1. `cardType=A&Return=True`
2. `cardType=AbC321`
3. `Return=False&cardType=C`

My current regex is:

```
cardType=(?<Card Type>.*)&?
```

This currently captures the 2 and 3, but not in 1 as it also captures `Return` in that case.

If I do instead:

```
cardType=(?<Card Type>.*?)&
```

Then it correctly captures 1, but not 2 and 3.

How do I write a regex that captures it in all 3 cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
cardType=(?<CardType>[^&\s]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h9vuX6/1)

Two important changes:

- removed space form group name
- replaced `.*)&?` with `[^&\s]*)`

The second change is more important. When you do .*&?, then `&?` is never captured, because `.*` takes the `&` sign.  As in most cases it's better to limit the repetition by limiting scope of accepted charactes to  `[^&\s]` - anything but whitespace or ampersand

Comment: Aha, thanks for the help. I see, you use the `[]` to go until you hit either a whitespace or an ampersand. I see putting the `[]` before  the * makes it work, but I'm not sure I understand why it has to go before the `*`, instead of after?

Comment: Operators, e.g. `*` or `?` affect subpatterns that are before them. So `.*` means "any number of any characters" and [^&]* means "any number of any character but &". `*.` or `*[^&]` make no sense.